# adding a column with variable name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to dynamically add som columns to 2 tables if they dont already exist.
My problem is, that the name of the column depends on another column's value.

But apparently the following is not allowed, why?

```
declare @inputs int; 
set @inputs = (select inputs from campaigns where id = 102) + 1; 
update campaigns set inputs = @inputs where id = 102; 
if col_length('campaigns', 'input' + @inputs) is null alter table campaigns add input' + @inputs + ' ntext null; 
if col_length('campaigns', 'input' + @inputs + 'text') is null alter table campaigns add input' + @inputs + 'ivocall ntext null; 
if col_length('rapports', 'input' + @inputs) is null alter table rapports add input' + @inputs + ' ntext null; 
if col_length('rapports', 'input' + @inputs + 'values') is null alter table rapports add input' + @inputs + 'values ntext null; 
update campaigns set input' + @inputs + ' = '1||test||||0||0||0||0||0||2||0' where id = 102
```

I get the following errors

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near ' + @inputs + '.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near ' + @inputs + '.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near ' + @inputs + '.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near ' + @inputs + '.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near ' + @inputs + '.
```

Comment: having column names depend on table values is almost certainly bad normalization at best

Comment: True.. And that will be corrected later on. But right now I need this to work somehow

Comment: @inputs its a int variable, and you're using like a literal string. Try to Cast it before use it. `+CAST(@inputs as varchar(50))+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this:

```
if col_length('campaigns', 'input' + @inputs) is null 
    alter table campaigns 
    add input' + @inputs + ' ntext null;
```

The third line is just not right, at best it should be:

```
if col_length('campaigns', 'input' + @inputs) is null 
    alter table campaigns 
    add 'input' + @inputs ntext null;
```

However, even that is not going to work. You're probably better off creating the whole DDL statement as a string, and then executing that. Something like:

```
set @sql = 'alter table campaigns add column input' + @inputs + ' ntext null'
exec (@sql)
```